# Reading clob columns from a database table(table includes other datatype columns as well)

Tags: database, plsql, clob

I have a table with several columns of mixed type. Some are varchar, some of type number and some of type clob.
The table creation query:

```
"create table tab1(id number,column1 varchar2,column2 clob,column3 varchar2,column4 clob,column5 number,column6 varchar2);"
```

I have been asked to read the values and store it in a csv file. How can I achieve it using only one loop that is for rows?

I tried reading values using this query:

```
"select id||','||column1||','||column2||','||column3||','||column4||','||column5||','||column6 from tab1"
```

but it is not possible to read the whole clob data this way. I cannot use a loop to read each column as the solution becomes expensive then for large set of columns.

Comment: Is this bad tagged? This seems to be a pure `oracle` question. How shall `apache poi` help here?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have corrected the tags.

Comment: If the CLOB columns can contain linefeeds and can be arbitrarily long then perhaps they are not suitable for CSV format.

Comment: What tool or language are you using to extract the CSV data to a file?

Comment: I am extracting CSV data into file using PL SQL